# R: Find/match NUTS code in shapefile

Tags: r, shapefile, r-sp, rgdal, r-maptools

where do I find the EU NUTS code in the shapefile in R?

*NUTS = Nomenclature of Territorial Units for Statistics*

Each NUTS region has a NUTS code:

[image: Example picture for Germany].

You can also find the detailed NUTS codes in [this Excel file](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/ramon/documents/nuts/NUTS_2013.zip).

When I download the NUTS shapefile, I cannot find this NUTS code.

I downloaded the shapefile **NUTS_2013_20M_SH.zip** from:

ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/gisco/geodata/reference-data/administrative-units-statistical-units/nuts#nuts13

After downloading, I upload the shapefile into R using the code:

```
library(sp)
library(rgdal)

dir <- setwd(getwd())

NUTS_shape = readOGR(dsn = (dsn = "~/NUTS_2013_20M_SH/data", layer = "NUTS_BN_20M_2013")
```

NOTE:

- `dsn =` is the path to the folder in which you saved the shapefile.
- `layer =` is the name of the file without the file extension (e.g., .shp)

If I use `summary(NUTS_shape)`, I only find a "NUTS_BN_ID" but no NUTS code. Also if I use `str(NUTS_shape[4461,])` to see the list structure of example-item 4461, it doesn't seem like there is a NUTS code.

Does anyone know if the NUTS shapefile contains the NUTS code or if the NUTS_BN_ID is somehow linked to this code?

Comment: Would be nice to get at least a comment instead of a "-1" rating. Otherwise, I have no idea what you dislike about my question.

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer:

In case someone is also working with NUTS data, then you will find the NUTS code not in the layer "NUTS_BN_20M_2013" but you have to use another layer, that is: "NUTS_RG_20M_2013".

Hence, use the code:

```
NUTS_shape = readOGR(dsn = (dsn = "~/NUTS_2013_20M_SH/data", layer = "NUTS_RG_20M_2013")
```

Then if you write `NUTS_shape@data` you get:

```
  NUTS_ID STAT_LEVL_  SHAPE_AREA SHAPE_LEN
0      AT          0 10.04269653 22.922441
1     AT1          1  2.84477225 10.876468
2    AT11          2  0.47903755  5.591853
3   AT111          3  0.08480488  1.178272
4   AT112          3  0.21836213  2.649698
5   AT113          3  0.17587054  2.276286
```

The NUTS_ID equals the code.